# Bool function for xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am practicing some bool functions and I seem to be stuck any help will be appreciated. I must be making some little mistake.

```
-(BOOL) checkForWin
{
    if ([[dictionary valueForKey:[cowsShuffled objectAtIndex:cowsCard]] intValue]  == 2{
       return YES;
    }
}

 -(void) moo 
{
    if (checkForWin == YES) {
        NSLog (@"foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code properly makes it easier for others to read it and thus help you. It also reduces the incidence of bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the method (not function), and you don't need to compare to YES. The `if` statement does that implicitly:

```
if ([self checkForWin]) …
```

Also note that `checkForWin` has a problem: it doesn't return anything if the `if` statement fails. It should be simply:

```
- (BOOL)checkForWin{
    return [[dictionary valueForKey:[cowsShuffled objectAtIndex:cowsCard]] intValue] == 2;
}
```

**Footnote:** Strictly speaking, `if (x) …` isn't exactly the same as `if (x == YES) …`. It's actually closer to `if (x != NO) …`, but of course that's the same thing for most intents and purposes (and those for which it isn't are largely pathological).

Answer (score 1):

Your method call is wrong. You call a method like this: `[object method]`.

In your case `[self checkForWin]`.